# HeidelTime: How to package HeidelTime correctly within a jar?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, uima, uimafit, heideltime

I use the HeidelTimeWrapper from [here](https://github.com/rudgertaxweiler/expert-profiling/blob/9d3ace3b79fcae24699337afbf7c199dd66b3ba9/src/main/java/br/ufsc/egc/rudger/expertprofiling/nlp/heideltime/HeidelTimeWrapper.java), added the parameter PARAM_TEMPONYMS to it and initialize it like this in my uimaFit Pipeline:

```
AnalysisEngineDescription heidelTimeEnglish = createEngineDescription(HeidelTimeWrapper.class, 
        HeidelTimeWrapper.PARAM_LANGUAGE, "english",
        HeidelTimeWrapper.PARAM_TYPE_TO_PROCESS, "narrative",
        HeidelTimeWrapper.PARAM_DATE, true, HeidelTimeWrapper.PARAM_DURATION, true,
        HeidelTimeWrapper.PARAM_TIME, true, HeidelTimeWrapper.PARAM_SET, true,
        HeidelTimeWrapper.PARAM_TEMPONYMS, false, HeidelTimeWrapper.PARAM_GROUP, true);
```

This solution works when running the application within Eclipse. But with this I get errors when packaging the application into a jar:

```
org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceInitializationException: Initialization of annotator class "de.ubt.ai4.ma.annotator.HeidelTimeWrapper" failed.  (Descriptor: <unknown>)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAnalysisComponent(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:268)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initialize(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:175)
        at org.apache.uima.impl.AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.produceResource(AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.java:94)
        at org.apache.uima.impl.CompositeResourceFactory_impl.produceResource(CompositeResourceFactory_impl.java:62)
        at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:279)
        at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(UIMAFramework.java:407)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.setup(ASB_impl.java:256)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initASB(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:435)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAggregateAnalysisEngine(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:379)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initialize(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:192)
        at org.apache.uima.impl.AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.produceResource(AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.java:94)
        at org.apache.uima.impl.CompositeResourceFactory_impl.produceResource(CompositeResourceFactory_impl.java:62)
        at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:279)
        at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(UIMAFramework.java:407)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.setup(ASB_impl.java:256)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initASB(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:435)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAggregateAnalysisEngine(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:379)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initialize(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:192)
        at org.apache.uima.impl.AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.produceResource(AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.java:94)
        at org.apache.uima.impl.CompositeResourceFactory_impl.produceResource(CompositeResourceFactory_impl.java:62)
        at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:279)
        at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:331)
        at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(UIMAFramework.java:448)
        at org.apache.uima.fit.factory.AnalysisEngineFactory.createEngine(AnalysisEngineFactory.java:205)
        at org.apache.uima.fit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:259)
        at org.apache.uima.fit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:292)
        at de.ubt.ai4.ma.annotator.NestedNamedEntityAnnotator.process(NestedNamedEntityAnnotator.java:37)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.process(JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.java:48)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:411)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.innerCall(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:329)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:321)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.processUntilNextOutputCas(ASB_impl.java:570)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.<init>(ASB_impl.java:412)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.process(ASB_impl.java:344)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:271)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.processUntilNextOutputCas(ASB_impl.java:570)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.<init>(ASB_impl.java:412)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.process(ASB_impl.java:344)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:271)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.process(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:269)
        at org.apache.uima.fit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:176)
        at de.ubt.ai4.ma.pipeline.MainPipeline.runMainPipelineClient(MainPipeline.java:89)
        at de.ubt.ai4.ma.application.controller.AnnotatorRESTController.annotate(AnnotatorRESTController.java:56)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at de.unihd.dbs.uima.annotator.heideltime.resources.NormalizationManager.<init>(NormalizationManager.java:63)
        at de.unihd.dbs.uima.annotator.heideltime.resources.NormalizationManager.getInstance(NormalizationManager.java:76)
        at de.unihd.dbs.uima.annotator.heideltime.HeidelTime.initialize(HeidelTime.java:153)
        at de.ubt.ai4.ma.annotator.HeidelTimeWrapper.initialize(HeidelTimeWrapper.java:40)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAnalysisComponent(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:261)
        ... 92 more
```

In my final jar, HeidelTime can't initialize or access its resource files. I am using the Spring Boot Maven Plugin and the Maven Assembly Plugin for building. Here is a snippet of my pom.xml:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>org/apache/uima/ruta/type/*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

In my jar, the packaging looks like this:

```
- arabic
- assets
- auto[-languagesOfHeidelTime]
- ...
- de (in here is the package unihd.unihd.dbs.uima.annotator.heideltime.HeidelTime, which contains the HeidelTime.class file)
- ...
```

How do you package HeidelTime correctly when building a jar with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite a few hours I solved my problem with the Spring Boot Maven Plugin.

The plugin has a parameter called [`<requiresUnpack>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html#requiresUnpack). Adding this parameter with the heideltime-dependency lets me package my application and run it successfully. I also got rid of the maven-assembly-plugin.

Here is the important snippet from my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
        <layout>ZIP</layout>
        <requiresUnpack>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.heideltime</groupId>
                <artifactId>heideltime</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </requiresUnpack>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution!